# How to make a multicolumn unordered list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a list of items that would look like this:

[image: floated list]

Main requirement is that the list should be flexible in a way that it's possible to add or remove list items without touching the code.

The best solution I found so far is to put all list items (including headers) into the `<li>` tags and style them with one of the techniques presented in this [A List Apart article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/multicolumnlists/):

```
<ul>
  <li class="header">Drinks</li>
  <li>Drink 1</li>
  <li>Drink 2</li>
  <li>Drink 3</li>
  <li class="header">Meat</li>
  <li>Meat 1</li>
  <li>Meat 2</li>
  <li>Meat 3</li>
  <li>Meat 4</li>
  <li>Meat 5</li>
  <li>Meat 6</li>
  etc.
</ul>
```

I was wondering if there are some better suggestions here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Also have a look at [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Comment: Will all the items be the same height?  How much pre-processing can you do (PHP etc)?  This is a tough one, HTML and CSS have never been made to accommodate fixed height layouts, in fact, just the opposite; The specs were designed to encourage either fixed or fluid width layouts that wrapped and compensated in height to any length of content.  Having a fixed height div (so wrapping bottom to top as opposed to right to left) is sort of contrary to that.  It still CAN be totally possible!  But that's entirely dependent on your requirements for the situation.

Comment: @mplungjan Looks interesting, thanks, I'll take a look.

Comment: @SandyGifford do you mean the `<li>` items? Yes, they will be the same height. I have basically total control of pre-processing so I can generate data in any format (using Django/Python).

Comment: I've added an answer below that does NOT depend on browsers having support for any `CSS` or `javascript`.  It's in PHP (I'm not familiar with Django or Python on the server side) but it shouldn't be hard to translate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the only way you can achieve this cleanly (without javascript) is using the `column-count` CSS property. IE only supports it from 10+ though: http://caniuse.com/multicolumn

Here's a demo: http://jsbin.com/efiqov/2/

Also, headers should be headers, not list items.

Comment: the CSS solution gave me problems with the vertical alignment. Here's a live example of how to do it with jquery (very easy): http://jsfiddle.net/EebVF/5 Using this jquery plugin: http://github.com/fzondlo/jquery-columns

Answer (score 2):

As long as you don't need to support older browsers you can just use CSS3 multi-columns...

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multicolumn.html

Then just use an unordered lists for each category.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily overcome this with css3 multi-colum. And for ie browsers you can use script too. see the link for more details

http://www.cvwdesign.com/txp/article/360/multi-column-layout-with-css3-and-some-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the complete ability to do pre-processing AND have fixed height `<li>`'s consider the following in PHP:

```
$menu=array(
    "header" => "Drinks",
    "item" => "Drink 1",
    "item" => "Drink 2",
    "item" => "Drink 3",
    "item" => "Drink 4",
    "header" => "Meats",
    "item" => "Meat 1",
    "item" => "Meat 2",
    "item" => "Meat 3",
    "item" => "Meat 4"
);

$item_count = 0;
$items_per_column = 5;

echo "<ul>";
foreach($menu as $key=>$value)
{
    if($item_count % $items_per_column == 0)
    {
        echo "</ul><ul>";
    }

    $item_count ++;

    echo "<li class='".$key."'>".$value."</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```

That's untested, but SHOULD work just fine.  Just give each `<ul>` a `float: left` and they'll stack next to eachother.

Comment: That's an interesting solution but I think I'll go with the multicolumn CSS solution for now as I can afford to ignore IE at this point (small and closed group of users). In any case, I appreciate your answer.

Comment: Just remember, that's IE and all older browsers.  Below is a full list indicating which versions of the most popular browsers STARTED including support for HTML5:


Internet Explorer 9 & 10
Firefox 7 and higher
Chrome 14 and higher
Safari 5 and higher
Opera 11 and higher
Mobile Safari 3.2 and higher
Opera Mobile 5 and higher
Android 2.1 and higher
[source](http://speckyboy.com/2012/03/25/getting-to-grips-with-html5-browser-compatibility/).  

Any browser with a lower version number WILL NOT SUPPORT that multi-column layout technique.

Comment: By not supporting IE 8.0 and Firefox 4.0 you're instantly cutting off the top 45% of internet users ([source](http://royal.pingdom.com/2011/06/17/report-the-most-common-web-browsers-and-browser-versions-today/)).  In fact, if you read down that source link (which, admittedly, is a year old) you'll notice that the first HTML5 compliant browser is IE 9, but by that point you've lost 77.96% of all browsers, and STILL there are non-HTML5 compliant browsers further in the list.  It's not just IE you're losing.

Comment: The problem with an approach like this is that you're arbitrarily chopping the lists, that's bad for bots/screen-readers/SEO. Doing it in javascript at leasts keeps the original HTML sane.

Comment: True enough about bots and screen readers, but that's an easy enough fix:  List of lists.  Still better than cutting out what is almost the entire internet with CSS3, and depending on scripting for the rest (you should always have a `noscript` alternative)

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally this is all you need, no css3, js, or php, works in any version of any browser, etc.

Four columns

```
li {width: 25%; float: left;}

<ul>
<li>content</li>
<li>content</li> etc.
</ul>
```

Three columns

```
li {width: 33%; float: left;}

<ul>
<li>content</li>
<li>content</li> etc.
</ul>
```

Etc.

Less is more, embrace simplicity!

Comment: That won't layout the result as in the OP's example.

Comment: As far as I can tell all he has is a simple autoflowing mutlicolumn list. Is he saying "not touching the code," as in he can add new items through some external interface, with actually adding new li's. I don't know about that. But as far as an autoflowing mutlicolumn ul, this is fundamentally all one needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this really easily with the [jQuery-Columns Plugin](http://github.com/fzondlo/jquery-columns) for example to split a ul with a class of .mylist into 5 columns you would do

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  $('.mylist').cols(5);
});
```

Here's a [live example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EebVF/5)