# How can I make a multi column html ul list?

Tags: php, html

How can I make a multi column html ul list without adding divs, classes, tables, etc. The raw html can't be altered, because it is output via PHP.

The PHP code outputs my list like this:

listitem1
listitem2
listitem3
listitem4
listitem5
listitem6
listitem7

I need mutli-column lists. It needs to fill up 1 column at a time, with 3 list items for each column with a 5px margin in-between each colummn. It should look like this:

listitem1  listitem4  listitem7
listitem2  listitem5
listitem3  listitem6

I don't know PHP so I have no idea how to output the ul list to have multi columns. Could anyone help?

Comment: Can you add the code to your question?

Comment: `ul` is a list, if you want columns, use `table`.

Comment: Can you use jquery...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a multicolumn unordered list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392891/how-to-make-a-multicolumn-unordered-list)

Comment: I can't add any code to the html list, it is a PHP output. I can't use JQuery. I'll try and find the PHP code that outputs the html list, and will post it here. But just note, I can't edit the raw html list myself.
It's not a duplicate. I can't edit the raw html list.

Comment: "How can I make a multi column html ul list without adding divs, classes, tables, etc." -  so what you can do?

Comment: If something is result of an PHP code just edit the PHP code output...

Comment: Ok, how would I use PHP to specify for that list to fill up 1 column at a time, with 3 list items for each column, with a 5px margin in-between each column?

Comment: You can use `table` just like @Notulysses said

Comment: I need to remind you, I can't edit the raw html. If I could, I could easily accomplish this with tables. But how do I integrate that with the PHP dynamic output. It isn't a static output, it is a dynamic one. I can't control how many columns will come up, either 2, 3 or 10.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the below code and try. You can use float : left for li elements.

```
<style type="text/css">
li{
list-style:none;
}

.grid ul{
list-style: none;
}
.grid ul li{
float: left;
margin-right:5px;
}
</style>

ul>
<li class="grid">
<ul>
<li> something1 </li>
<li> something1 </li>
<li> something1 </li>
</ul>
</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: I pasted it on jsfiddle. It doesn't give me separate columns going downwards. It just gives me one horizontal line of text, with the words 5px apart.

Comment: addd js fiddle url with that comment and let me check